# How to add custom font in python-flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have tried using @fontface css style, but the font doesn't get rendered.
Is there another way of doing this using python/flask??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: trial;
src: url_for('CENTRALESANSCND-BOLD.otf') ;
font-weight:bold; }

</style>
<body>

<p style="font-family:trial; font-weight: bold"> Hello </p>

</body>
</html>
```

The above is my HTML template.
Unfortunately, when I render it using Flask, it doesn't reflect the font.
The following is my .py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='1234'

@app.route('/', methods=['post', 'get'])
def output():
    c=2+3
    print c

    return render_template('f.html', c=c)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=9876)
```

Comment: Please paste code from your templates so we can make an idea of what's not working.

Comment: Please refer the codes attached above..

Comment: Check the `src` attribute in the source of your `html` page. Is the url correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct. plus if I render the html page as such without using Flask, I am able to see the new font.

Comment: Have you made a `static` folder as specified here, try using that method => [Flask static files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files)

Comment: Tried that as well.. Didn't work.. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all your help.. A combination of all the suggestions finally worked.

Posting the solution here:

CSS file:

```
@font-face{
font-family: trial;
src: url('CENTRALESANSCND-BOLD.otf');
font-weight: bold;}

body {font-family: georgia; color:green}
h1 {font-family:trial; color: pink}
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='mystyle.css')}}"/> 
<body>

<p > Hello... </p>
<h1> welcome </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

url_for takes a function name, and you need to wrap it in double curly brackets... try:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
    font-family: trial;
    src: {{ url_for('static', filename='CENTRALESANSCND-BOLD.otf') }};
    font-weight:bold; }
</style>
```

Comment: Tried this as well.. Its not working! Is there any other way other than using `@font-face`??

Answer (score 1):

```
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: FontName;
      src: url("{{ url_for('static', filename='FontFile.otf') }}");
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I think your main point is that the "url()" wrapping was missing, right? It always helps if you write a small explanation for your answer so people don't have to go back and forth to compare what's different between your answer and the other answers.