# How to add custom fonts to Flask?

Tags: html, css, flask, fonts

I have my own font and I've created their webkit, however I can't load it.

I have used the font previously in some android and desktop apps it runs perfectly.

I've tried in 3 different ways, usign the same app.py file

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def start():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Attempt # 1**

folder structure

```
-static
--css
---stylesheet.css
---myfont.ttf
-templates
--index.html
```

stylesheet.css

```
@font-face{
font-family: myfont;
src: ('myfont.ttf');
}
p {font-family:myfont; color:blue}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/stylesheet.css')}}" type="text/css"/>
<body>
<p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Attempt #2**

folder structure

```
-static
--css
---stylesheet.css
---myfont.ttf
---myfont.eot
---myfont.svg
---myfont.woff
-templates
--index.html
```

stylesheet.css

```
@font-face{
font-family: myfont;
src: ('myfont.eot');
src: ('myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     ('myfont.woff') format('woff'),
     ('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     ('myfont.svg#myfont') format('svg');
}
p {font-family:myfont; color:blue}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/stylesheet.css')}}" type="text/css" />
<body>
<p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Attempt #3**

folder structure

```
-static
--fonts
---stylesheet.css
---myfont.ttf
---myfont.eot
---myfont.svg
---myfont.woff
-templates
--index.html
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
    <style>
    @font-face{
    font-family: myfont;
    src: {{ url_for('static',filename='fonts/myfont.eot') }};
    src: {{ url_for('static',filename='fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix') }} format('embedded-opentype'),
         {{ url_for('static',filename='fonts/myfont.woff') }} format('woff'),
         {{ url_for('static',filename='fonts/myfont.ttf') }} format('truetype'),
         {{ url_for('static',filename='fonts/myfont.svg#myfont') }} format('svg');
    }
    p {font-family:myfont; color:green}

    </style>
<body>
<p>prueba</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have checked out this links, but the result is negative again

[How do you upload a font to your webpage (is the server needed)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940575/how-do-you-upload-a-font-to-your-webpage-is-the-server-needed)

[How to add custom font in python-flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582644/how-to-add-custom-font-in-python-flask)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `Flask` with `render_template`, your root directory should look like this:

- `app.py`
- `static/style.css`
- `templates/index.html`

You have to specify your `css` file inside a `static` folder and html files inside the `templates` folder.

After that, add this into your `html` file:

```html
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" 
    href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You must come back to root directory and then give the directory for stylesheet.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='../css/stylesheet.css')}}" type="text/css"/>`

and why do you use this type of incuding?
use this :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styesheet.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: I tried both options but now I'm getting a 404 error that I wasn't getting before.